# Reaver stuck at flow_handler

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wps

I tried to run Reaver against my router at home using an Ubuntu 15.10 laptop. The command used was: `sudo reaver -i mon0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -vv -c 7 -a` (the channel I got from `airodump-ng`).

I'm aware, that a brute force will take some time, but as far as I know, Reaver should output the attempted pins. That doesn't happen for me. On the bottom line is written `flow_handler` and I think, it's stuck there.

Does this mean the AP is immune against Reaver (it has WPS enabled)? Or is the problem on my side (which I guess)? If so, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: what kind of wifi adapter are you using? also, please provide all of the commands you executed prior to running reaver (i.e. airmon-ng start wlan0, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

There's much to be done before you can get a correct answer for this situation.

- First, and most simple solution, you can check your AP manufacture website to be sure if it's immune to WPS PIN attacks.
- Second, try to use another wireless card, and most important, don't use your laptop WiFi card if your running Ubuntu through a virtual machine.
- Also, try to use another tool, or another version of Reaver.
- Also try the same tool on another AP which you already know it's vulnerable to WPS attacks.

If you had further results, it might help us.

Comment: Emadeddin is right. Maybe, some wireless card chipsets are not compatible with reaver. For example Ralink. If you have a Ralink card, forget to use reaver... you must use other tool, bully.